# Holiday lens - 18-200 or 18-250

Tags: lens

I'm off on holiday soon and I want to get an all-around lens which I'm sure is one of the most read topics on the internet.
I have a Canon 450D and I've been looking at the Canon or Sigma lens as they both have stabilization. 
I've been looking at either the 18-200 or 18-250.
Which one should I go for or do you have any other suggestions?
I want one lens so I don't have to keep swapping and I know I'm going to lose some quality.

Comment: Which lenses do you mean by "18-200" or "18-250"? Please give exact names.

Comment: Also note that the topic of super zoom lenses has been covered repeatedly on the site.  Short story version, it doesn't particularly matter because super zooms don't do all that well in general because they have to compromise too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.juzaphoto.com/article.php?l=en&article=35

conculsion from this site:

> If I had to choose between these four superzooms, I'd go for the
>   Canon. At the shorter focal lenght they are all about the same, but
>   the Canon has a clear advantage at the longest FL, in spite of the
>   slightly shorter reach. If you are looking for a super small and
>   versatile lens for your trips or holidays, the Canon 18-200 may be the
>   lens for you, if you can accept the limits of a superzoom (not very
>   bright, chromatic aberration, distortion, not as sharp as more limited
>   zooms).     The Sigma and the Tamrons are about on par; the Tamron
>   18-250 is the best of the three, in terms of optical quality at
>   "normal" distances, while the Tamron 18-270 is the best for macro work
>   (even though all them are way worse than a real macro lens).